# sms no longer received by smart phone

Tags: python-3.10

for quite some time I could send sms from my raspberry pi (ZeroW) to my smart phone.

Using the following python code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from pushbullet import Pushbullet
import logging

PUSHBULLET_API_KEY = "my api-key"
PHONE_NUMBER = "my phone number"


logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/pi/mylog1.log', filemode='w',\
                    format="%(asctime)s -%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",\
                    level=logging.INFO)

push_bullet = Pushbullet(PUSHBULLET_API_KEY)

def push_to_bullet(push_bullet):
    try:
        push_bullet.push_sms(push_bullet.devices[0], PHONE_NUMBER, "PIR home Bonda activated")
        logging.info("sms sent")
    except Exception:
        logging.exception("sms error")

push_to_bullet(push_bullet)
```

I'm getting confirmation from python in the log file but no sms show up on my smart phone

I checked my Android pushbullet pro app on my smart phone forwards and backwards and
found no solution.